# How to merge datasets based on an identifier which is non-unique in both datasets

Tags: merge, stata, panel-data

When in Stata two data sets shall be merged, based on one variable that is non-unique in either of the data sets, merge x:x does not appear to be a useful tool. What strategy would yield the desired results?

**Stylized example:**

*Dataset1*

```
AssetManager | Bankcode
A              1
B              2
B              3
C              3
```

*Dataset2*

```
Bankcode | t    
1          t1          
1          t2     
2          t1    
2          t2    
3          t1    
3          t2
```

*Aim:*

```
AssetManager | Bankcode | t
A              1         t1
A              1         t2
B              2         t1
B              2         t2
B              3         t1
B              3         t2
C              3         t1
C              3         t2
```

*Intuition: 
Some asset managers can by held by multiple banks, while some banks also own multiple asset managers.*

Comment: Rather than `merge x:x`, I think you mean `merge m:m`.

Comment: Merge `x:x` was meant to include `1:m, m:1, m:m`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of `merge m:m` is discouraged (read the corresponding entries in the Stata manuals), and many people support its elimination. Try `joinby`:

```
clear
set more off

input ///
str1 AssetManager Bankcode
A              1
B              2
B              3
C              3
end

tempfile first
save "`first'"

clear

input ///
Bankcode str2 t    
1          t1          
1          t2     
2          t1    
2          t2    
3          t1    
3          t2    
end

joinby Bankcode using "`first'"

sort AssetManager Bankcode t
order AssetManager Bankcode
list, sepby(AssetManager)
```